# AWS Serverless : Token authentification

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I'm working on a project that uses aws lambdas coded in NodeJS for the backend. It is hosted in serverless mode in AWS. I use cognito as an authentification API and I can successfully get the token from it. To secure my back-end (NodeJS), i added the following code to read the authorization header and validate the token using cognito-express.

```
  const authorisedRoute = express.Router();
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');  
   if (req.method !== 'OPTIONS') {
    let accessTokenFromClient = req.headers['Authorization'];
    if (!accessTokenFromClient) return res.status(401).send("Access Token missing from header");

    cognitoExpress.validate(accessTokenFromClient, function (err, response) {
    if (err) return res.status(401).send(err);
    else next();   
    });

    } 
    });
```

**Expected behavior :**
Token is read from the "Authorization" Header and is validated using cognito-express, then data is sent back to the client. If it's not validated i get : Missing Authentication Token.

**Actual behavior:**
The code and this mechanism works fine when running lambda's locally (amplify invoke function ...). But when i deploy it to the cloud, the whole function stops working and i get "Internal processing error" as a response .

Is that method not allowed in the cloud ? Is there a better way to secure my serverless api using token authentication ?
Thank you for reading this :)

Comment: `the whole function stops working and i get "Internal processing error" as a response` could you be more specific and find any more details about the error? As well you could consider using an [authorizer lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html)

Comment: @gusto2 That's what's make my problem difficult. When running lambda's locally, i do have console logs. Once deployed to the clouds, i have no way of having detailed logs. And again, it works perfectly locally and not in the cloud ...

Comment: Give your lambda `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` permissions (or other allowing to write to the CloudWatch logs), you will have your logs in the CloudWatch. As well you could run your Lambda manually with a proper event object.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I've managed to access the logs, but enabling token authentification through code didn't work . I've managed to do that by adding an authentication mechanism in the API Gateway, then configuring each route to check for a token in the authorization header , setting the scope to my cognito user group .